# Generate uniq hard-to-pick-up num from id

Tags: algorithm, hash

We have a table with records with simple incremental IDs, estimated capacity is 10.000.000 records. I need to generate 12-16 long uniq number from the ID which will be relatively hard to pickup manually (similar to credit card numbers, but no need to real brute force resistance, just make it hard for users to enter someone's else number).

What are best practices for such tasks? What should I google for?

Comment: Why does it need to be generated from the ID? Just generate a random string and put it into a column in the table so you can search for it.

Comment: Add a UUID column and generate UUIDs for all the records. Use those as the key rather than the simple incremental id

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. The numbers must be uniq and easy for users to enter manually. That's why we have limitation on the size and to numbers only.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for security, this is absolutely the wrong way to go about this. If you really need them to be secret, then generate them on the server and use a key exchange to establish auth before sending them to the client.

Comment: It's not really about security, and number will be generated on the server anyway. It's a number printed on a receipt in a store. Users will later use it to claim some bonuses on the website based on their order.